# Web app design question: file import and/or web edit ui?

Tags: php, web-applications, user-interface, user-input

The situation:
We collect a large form's worth of information from the user.
Each user fills out around one to ten forms around the same time twice a year.
The form is only later edited in the uncommon case of information needing to be updated or corrected.
Users are clients( or peons thereof ) that are required to fill out the forms as part of using our company's services.

Originally this was all done with a web form, with support for saving progress and measuring completion.

Later, the form was expanded to include "List each of your pets: name, species, age".
The web UI was expanded to handle this, and also an excel template was created which could be downloaded, filled out, and submitted to the app to complete this part of the form.

Users seemed to like this, and infact, one asked us if we could implement the entire form as an excel template file to be filled out and submitted.  This sounded to me like a good idea at the time and was filed away in my brain drawer.

The form is once again being updated and expanded and we are going to put in the "full" excel import option.

Thank you for reading this far! Here is the question:

Since the entire form can be handled as an excel file and is not supposed to be edited regularly, is a web editing interface neccesary?  Would users come for us pitchforks in hand if we took it away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, handling all different kinds of excel-formats (95/97/XP whatnot), isn't easy (if even possible) in PHP. So in my opinion, you need to give the users an ability to do things "manually" when things go wrong (they will).

Also, not everyone has Excel (or a spreadsheet capable of saving in Excel-format), so those users probably won't like it one bit.

Answer (score 1):

Not everybody owns a copy of Microsoft Excel. If the clients are required to fill in these forms they are also required to buy a copy of Excel.

Comment: On my box I use openoffice calc with it ;p

Comment: Yes, OpenOffice Calc might do it, but can you guarantee that all possible free alternatives to Excel will handle these forms in the exact same way?

Comment: Probably not, but the users aren't consumers, they are organizations, and we are in direct contact with them, so if for some reason one of them couldn't use excel they would let us know.  I would be surprised if any of them even use calc.

Comment: Ok then, there is your answer. If they would let you know by means of pitchforks though is impossible to predict. :)

Answer (score 0):

IF your question is about how to present the user with their last (old) information because it is likely that very little has altered since their previous submission, then that maybe you have an inhouse failure to return this back to the user in a usable format - if so, then yes, you should expect them to come for you with pitchforks.

Perhaps you mean they can retrieve (part of) their old record as say, a flat csv file, edit it and resubmit it as csv.

Answer (score 0):

I second the opinion Excel shoudn't be your be all and end all. I have done Excel imports in the past using:

[phpExcelReader](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/)

It seems fairly reliable and can understand the older excel documents, haven't tested the new. (User can just save in comparability mode).

If I went to a company and they handed me an Excel Template, I'd use a pitch fork, sledge hammer and anything else I could find. Another point is it's not "future proof" in the slightest. Web interfaces can be used on Androids, iPhones, Macs and PC's. Excel?

P.S. I suppose if you managed to get the template working in OpenOffice it wouldn't be so bad...